# How get translation from Google Translate API v2 php?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-translate

I using https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client for translate.

When I try

```
print_r($translation->listTranslations( "John go home", "es" ));
```

I got

```
Google_Service_Translate_TranslationsListResponse Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => translations
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )
    [translationsType:protected] => Google_Service_Translate_TranslationsResource
    [translationsDataType:protected] => array
    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [translations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [translatedText] => John ir a casa
                                    [detectedSourceLanguage] => en
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

But when I try to get translations using getTranslations() function - i got empty array. Please advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the library is broken.

You can use this to get the translations out though!

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxx-your-dev-key-xxxx');


$translate = new Google_Service_Translate($client);
$translations = $translate->translations->listTranslations('Hello world!', 'fr');


var_dump($translations->data);
var_dump($translations->data['translations'][0]["translatedText"]);
```

Will give you

```
array(1) {
  ["translations"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["translatedText"]=>
      string(17) "Bonjour le monde!"
      ["detectedSourceLanguage"]=>
      string(2) "en"
    }
  }
}
string(17) "Bonjour le monde!"
```

I submitted a [PR that fixes this](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/pull/862), but it hasn't been accepted yet.